# Получить содержимое дива с сайта. node.js

Tags: node.js

Нужно получить получить текст с сайта http://status.hirezstudios.com, а именно:
[image: состояние сервера Smite PC]

т.е. состоянии сервера Smite PC, там может быть under maintenance и т.п.. 
Я так понял нужен именно этот див:
[image: div]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вытащить оттуда текст?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если можно установить [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) и `id` селектора не изменится, можно так:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('http://status.hirezstudios.com/');

    const status = await page.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector(
        'div[data-component-id="23d1x2hb4kyq"] span.component-status'
      ).innerText.trim()
    );

    console.log(status);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```